Page and page frames
Consider a paged memory system whose pages are 4kB in size. Each entry in the system page table is 4 Bytes, and contains only the minimum information (i.e. only the bits to represent presence, frame number, protection, reference and modification). The page table is multilevel, constituting a 1st level table with 32k entries and a 2nd level in which each entry fits exactly on one page. Indicate a) the number of real address header bits, b) the capacity of the RAM (real memory) of this system, c) the number of entries in each 2nd level paging table and d) the capacity of the virtual memory of this system.
I understood some parts of the problem, but I actually do not know how to solve it. It is a little bit confusing.

The statement "a 2nd level in which each entry fits exactly on one page." is nonsense.  Maybe a typo and should be "a 2nd level in which each table fits exactly on one page."

This was a question from an exam of my OS course, that part about the 2nd level is confusing me. The way you said seems more clear.
